# PowerShell, only "> $out" catch full error of failed 7Zip extract, why?

Tags: powershell, error-handling, 7zip

I tried all suggestion on how to catch errors of 7Zip as explained in:

- [powershell - How to capture output in a variable rather than a logfile? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423368/how-to-capture-output-in-a-variable-rather-than-a-logfile)
- [Redirecting output to $null in PowerShell, but ensuring the variable remains set - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881174/redirecting-output-to-null-in-powershell-but-ensuring-the-variable-remains-set)

and played with try / catch.

Second contains only

> Cannot find drive. A drive with the name ' 7-Zip 18.05 (x64) ' does
> not exist.

in `Error[0]`

If I write the console output

```
7-Zip 18.05 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2018-04-30

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 51273 bytes (51 KiB)

Extracting archive: \\...\850\DAY01
--
7z.exe : ERROR: Data Error : DAY01.RAW
At C:\Users\MyUser\Code\7Zip.ps1:6 char:1
+ & $7ZIP_FullPath x $IN_FullPath -o$OUT_Directory -y
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: Data Error : DAY01.RAW:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
Path = \\...\850\DAY01
Type = gzip
Headers Size = 20


Sub items Errors: 1

Archives with Errors: 1

Sub items Errors: 1
```

in a variable, the variable will contain only

```
7-Zip 18.05 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2018-04-30

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 51273 bytes (51 KiB)

Extracting archive: \\...\850\DAY01
--    
Path = \\...\850\DAY01
Type = gzip
Headers Size = 20


Sub items Errors: 1

Archives with Errors: 1

Sub items Errors: 1
```

It looks like, that

```
7z.exe : ERROR: Data Error : DAY01.RAW
    At C:\Users\MyUser\Code\7Zip.ps1:6 char:1
    + & $7ZIP_FullPath x $IN_FullPath -o$OUT_Directory -y
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: Data Error : DAY01.RAW:String) [], RemoteException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

is created by PowerShell (what explaiuns `7z.exe : ERROR:..`) and can only be captured if I use `$out`:

```
& $7ZIP_FullPath x $IN_FullPath -o$OUT_Directory -y > $out
```

It looks like $out triggers something but what?

Comment: `> $out` sends the output, which would have been written to the console, to a file with the name given by the variable `$out`.  I'm guessing you aren't setting `$out` so this would be effectively be `> $nul`.

Comment: You could try `$out = & $7ZIP_FullPath x $IN_FullPath -o$OUT_Directory -y *>&1`

Comment: `$out` is not defined but I can use it when I do `write-host $out` afterwards. Wondering how to capture the error properly. Moreover, it looks like that PowerShell IDE and VS Code behave differently

Comment: @Daniel  `$7ZIPExtractResult= & $7ZIP_FullPath x $IN_FullPath -o$OUT_Directory -y *>&1` but not clue why. In addition `$7ZIPExtractResult` is `System.Object[]`, so I have to do `7ZIPExtractResultAsString` but there is no error thrown if I use `try` and `catch`  to I have to check the returning string, why ever???

Answer (score 1):

7zip is not a PowerShell command so you can’t use the ordinary try{}catch{} with the -ErrorAction Stop

But 7zip has the ability to send out the %errorlevel% values in batch. Which is a better way to find an error

So According to the documentation these are the possible exit codes (%ERRORLEVEL% values):
Code    Meaning

==== =======

0          No error

1          Warning (Non fatal error(s)). For example, one or more files were
locked by
some other application, so they were not compressed.

2          Fatal error

7          Command line error

8          Not enough memory for operation

255      User stopped the process

==== =======

In cmd or in a .bat file, there is no problem to run the 7zip command, and on the second line take out the %errorlevel% value, but in powershell you can’t really do that.

If you write the following code in powershell

To Zip:

```
& cmd.exe /c 'C:\"Program Files"\7-Zip\7z.exe a –mx1 "c:\DestinationFolder\NameOnZipFiles" c:\FolderToZip\*&echo:%errorlevel%'
```

To Unzip:

```
& cmd.exe /C 'C:\"Program Files"\7-Zip\7z.exe x "c:\SourceFolder" -o"D:\DestinationFolder" -y&echo:%errorlevel%'
```

You will notice that the %errorlevel% will always be 0, even if the command fails.
That’s because the %errorlevel% you get is the errorlevel before the command has run.

So to fix that problem you will have to enable the “DelayedExpansion” in cmd with “cmd.exe /v /c
the “%” will also have to be changed to “!” to use the delayed function.

So the correct command needs to be written like this to get the correct errorlevel

To Zip:

```
& cmd.exe /v /c 'C:\"Program Files"\7-Zip\7z.exe a –mx1  "c:\DestinationFolder\NameOnZipFiles" c:\FolderToZip\*&echo:!errorlevel!'
```

To Unzip:

```
& cmd.exe /v /C 'C:\"Program Files"\7-Zip\7z.exe x "c:\SourceFolder" -o"D:\DestinationFolder" -y&echo:!errorlevel!'
```

More info about the “DelayedExpansion” in cmd https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Also If you only want to display the errorlevel after command has run, add the following 7zip options “-bso0 -bsp0 -bse0”

To Zip:

```
& cmd.exe /v /c 'C:\"Program Files"\7-Zip\7z.exe a –mx1 "c:\DestinationFolder\NameOnZipFiles" c:\FolderToZip\* -bso0 -bsp0 -bse0&echo:!errorlevel!'
```

To Unzip:

```
& cmd.exe /v /C 'C:\"Program Files"\7-Zip\7z.exe x "c:\SourceFolder" -o"D:\DestinationFolder" –y -bso0 -bsp0 -bse0&echo:!errorlevel!'
```

But in your case, if your only after having the error text in the same variable just add the 7zip option -bse1

```
$out=& $7ZIP_FullPath x $IN_FullPath -o$OUT_Directory -y -bse1
```

Answer (score 0):

@daniel comments got me on the right track but still, I can not explain fully why only this solution is working.

```
$7ZIPExtractResult= & $7ZIP_FullPath x $IN_FullPath -o$OUT_Directory -y *>&1
```

> Redirects the specified stream to the Success stream.

My guess is, that only that way it can be stored in a variable.
I found help in [What does 2>&1 Mean in PowerShell - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931338/what-does-21-mean-in-powershell) and [about_Redirection - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.1).

In addition, the variable `$7ZIPExtractResult` is a `System.Object[]`, so I have to do convert [an array to a string](https://teckangaroo.com/how-to-convert-array-to-string-in-powershell/) doing `7ZIPExtractResultAsString = "$7ZIPExtractResult"`, expecting that is always possible and not throwing a different error.

It is still unknown to me why this error is not caught by

```
try {
}
catch {
}
```